# Translations issues, missing pipe

Tags: internationalization, translation, spartacus-storefront

Im trying to add translations to spartacus. I managed to change config and have the regular translation JSON on my local, but when I try to add new translations to my HTML i always get the same issue:

> "ERROR Error: The pipe 'cxTranslate' could not be found!"

This is what I have in my code:

```
<label for="sortDocType">Type of document: {{ 'common.back' | cxTranslate }}</label>
```

And my config Module:

```
import { ConfigModule, I18nConfig } from '@spartacus/core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { translationChunksConfig } from '@spartacus/assets';    
@NgModule({
      declarations: [],
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.withConfig({
          i18n: {
            backend: {
              loadPath: '../../assets/i18n-assets/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
            },
            chunks: {
              ...translationChunksConfig,
            },
            fallbackLang: 'en'
          },
        } as I18nConfig)
      ],
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Please import `I18nModule` in the same module that *declares* your custom component:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    I18nModule,
    /*...*/
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyComponent,
    /*...*/
  ],
  /*...*/
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Comment: I added the module but what I see now its: [filters:filters.typeofdoc] instead of the translation.
Maybe I need to import something else

Comment: I still have some issues with the translations. I added my imports on the question. I think translations model are missing? I dont know how to import them on local. I think its importing spartacus/core models.

Comment: Spartacus provides default translation chunks, defining in which chunk a translation can be found. You can see it in the following file: `projects/assets/src/translations/translation-chunks-config.ts`
`filters` is not provided in there, that's why it might not get translated due to fact that the translation chunk could not be found.

Comment: Btw. Please don't use spread operator in the config provided statically. Angular sometimes has problems with swallowing it `...translationChunksConfig` -> `translationChunksConfig`. If you really need to merge objects, please do it in a factory (`provideConfigFactory`).

Comment: Another thing: did you try setting simply relative path `assets/.......` without preceding `../../`? I'm not sure ../../ will work TBH